# memory leak running application build with 32bit Windows machine on 64bit machine

Tags: python, memory-leaks

We have a application(exe) which has a process who's memory usage is increasing gradually on 64bit windows but on 32bit machine it remains stable at certain limit.

The product is build on 32bit Windows XP.

```
------------------------Memory usage
Client Start - 24092 K
After 24hrs  - 81584 K

Windows XP - 32bit
-----------------------Memory usage
Client Start - 10598 K
After 24hrs  - 28548 K
```

1) So my question is: Can it be that due to running **32bit** application on **64bit** machine the memory usage is increasing?

2) Do I have to build separately for **64bit** Windows using **64bit python**? will this help?

3) There must be a memory leak in the code?

Comment: under 64 bit windows that there's no easy way to build your c extensions.

Comment: You have a .exe... in Python?

Comment: It looks like you have some startup data structures which are (naturally) bigger in the 64-bit environment and then you're leaking pointers (or longs) in both environments. The growth is close enough that you may have the same leak in both environments. ~44% larger memory footprint on 64 at start and then ~31% larger increase in footprint over time

Comment: May be you can compare 48hr 32-bit with 24hr 64-bit memory usage and with similar load/activity of your program.